# how to findone using multiple parameter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

wanted to findOne using multiple parameter but ended in an error. tempUser can be inputed as username,email,mobilePhone

heres the code

```
const tempUser = req.body.input;
const user = await User.findOne({
     $or:
         [
            {username : tempUser},
            {mobilePhone : tempUser},
            {email : tempUser}
         ]
})
```

here are the collection example

```
{
        "_id": "6531357830074bf5dfacb2de",
        "username": "elsa",
        "email": "elsa@gmail.com",
        "role": 4,
        "mobilePhone": 81702333244,
        "password": "elsa1234frozen",
        "__v": 0
},
```

if i inputed tempUser as mobilePhone (ex : 81234567891) it return the correct collection, but if i inputed tempUser as either username or email it error. then i try using promise aswell it error, the error said that findOne() doesnt need callback anymore

i was expecting if i inputed either username,email, and mobilePhone to return the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it that way because `mobilePhone` is defined as a `Number` so mongoose will always try to cast the value of `tempUser` to a `Number` so it can do an equality check. When you pass a `String` mongoose will throw a:

> Cast to Number failed for value "a string here" (type string) at path "mobilePhone" for model "User"

What you can do instead is just check if the value passed in `tempUser` is a `Number` and construct your query object as necessary.

Something like this will help you achieve the desired result:

```js
const tempUser = req.body.input;
let query;
if (isNaN(tempUser)) {
    query = {$or: [{username : tempUser}, {email : tempUser}]}
}else{
   query = {mobilePhone : tempUser}
}
const user = await User.findOne(query);
```

Or for a more concise one liner using the [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) if you prefer:

```js
const tempUser = req.body.input;
const query = isNaN(tempUser) ? {$or: [{username : tempUser}, {email : tempUser}]} : {mobilePhone : tempUser};
const user = await User.findOne(query);
```